# when i am adding android support library v7 app compact not install error

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi every one i have problem in adding the support library in android studio when i am trying to add library from maven library its shows error v7 appcompat is not install
**Library appcompat-v7 is not installed. Install repository?**

when i click it to install android studio error shows

**Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.**
i dont know what should i do

Comment: make sure everything(repository, support library version) in SDK manager is up to date.

Comment: @WenChao i was working on android studio 1.2 it was working fine i upgrade it to 1.3 and update sdk to the its arise problem